# Пайтон.Как подсчитать сумму двух последних цифр в числе Х

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как подсчитать сумму двух последних цифр в числе  Х.(Пользователь задает число сам)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Математический способ:

```py
x = 177013  # int(input())

result = x % 100 // 10 + x % 10  # 4
```

Способ через срез строки:

```py
x = '177013'  # input()

result = sum(map(int, x[-2:]))  # 4
```