# сумма последних двух цифр равна 6

Tags: python

Само задание: (А. Куканова)

> Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [1985; 8528], которые удовлетворяют следующим условиям:
>
> − сумма последних двух цифр равна 6;
>
> − не кратны 2, 7 и 47.
>
> Найдите максимальное из таких чисел и последние 3 цифры произведения всех таких чисел.

Кроме первого условия все остальное понятно, как записать первое условие кодом?

Comment: [Как подсчитать сумму двух последних цифр в числе Х](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058011)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо. все сделал